# playwright python handling child window (Popup)

Tags: python, playwright-python

I want to scrap child (Popup) on this page :

https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/audi,2022,a4,2.0l+l4+electric/gas+turbocharged,3449631,engine,oil+filter,5340

Here is the code

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
        
        
        
        def handle_popup(popup):
            popup.wait_for_load_state()
            print(popup.title())
            print("NEW POPUP")
     
        browser =  playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])
        context =  browser.new_context( no_viewport=True)
        page =  context.new_page()
        page.on("popup", handle_popup)
           
        page.goto('https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/audi,2022,a4,2.0l+l4+electric/gas+turbocharged,3449631,engine,oil+filter,5340',timeout=900000)
        page.on("popup", handle_popup)
        sleep(15)
        page.on("popup", handle_popup)
        soup = BeautifulSoup( page.content(), 'html.parser')
            
        #print(soup.prettify())
        context.close()
        browser.close()
        
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Issue is that popup hander code is never invoked. HTML captured is on parent page and not child window, Please help

Comment: Could you explain what mean `child (Popup)`? I don't see any popup's

Comment: I do not see any pop up either